# Extract the last directory of a pwd output

Tags: bash, unix, pwd

How do I extract the last directory of a pwd output? I don't want to use any knowledge of how many levels there are in the directory structure. If I wanted to use that, I could do something like:

```
> pwd
/home/kiki/dev/my_project
> pwd | cut -d'/' -f5
my_project
```

But I want to use a command that works regardless of where I am in the directory structure. I assume there is a simple command to do this using awk or sed.

Comment: What if your working directory is / ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Are you looking for [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) or [dirname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname)?

Something like

```
basename "`pwd`"
```

should be what you want to know.

If you insist on using `sed`, you could also use

```
pwd | sed 's#.*/##'
```

Comment: Or, more likely `endpath=$(basename $(pwd))`.

Comment: Missing quotes around "$(pwd)".  Try this without the quotes:

    mkdir "ab b"; cd "ab b"
    endpath=$(basename "$(pwd)")

Answer (score 26):

If you want to do it completely within a bash script without running any external binaries, `${PWD##*/}` should work.

Comment: Up to a point...if you arrived at the directory via a symlink with a different name, then the $PWD value will be different from the value produced by /bin/pwd or /usr/bin/pwd (which is distinct from the pwd built-in).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: The questioner used the pwd built-in, so I feel it was appropriate to use $PWD.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what the ##*/ are doing exactly? Thank you.

Comment: I found it it's command substitution: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 5):

Should work for you:
`pwd | rev | cut -f1 -d'/' - | rev`

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728689/663058

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. I'm quite fond of this method. If there's a good reason, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this either. Works for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that I do it is simply:

```bash
pwd | xargs basename
```