# Remove part of path on Unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed

I'm trying to remove part of the path in a string. I have the path:

```
/path/to/file/drive/file/path/
```

I want to remove the first part `/path/to/file/drive` and produce the output:

```
file/path/
```

Note: I have several paths in a while loop, with the same `/path/to/file/drive` in all of them, but I'm just looking for the 'how to' on removing the desired string.

I found some examples, but I can't get them to work:

```
echo /path/to/file/drive/file/path/ | sed 's:/path/to/file/drive:\2:'
echo /path/to/file/drive/file/path/ | sed 's:/path/to/file/drive:2'
```

`\2` being the second part of the string and I'm clearly doing something wrong...maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can also use POSIX shell variable expansion to do this.

```
path=/path/to/file/drive/file/path/
echo ${path#/path/to/file/drive/}
```

The `#..` part strips off a leading matching string when the variable is expanded;  this is especially useful if your strings are already in shell variables, like if you're using a `for` loop.  You can strip matching strings (e.g., an extension) from the end of a variable also, using `%...`.  See the `bash` man page for the gory details.

Comment: Thanks...Yes, I am using shell variables to perform this. Both parts are variables, the one I need to delete and the full path.

Comment: Excellent! But how can I use this when the string is coming "from a pipe"?

Comment: @Birger if the string is coming from a pipe then you need to get it into a variable to use shell variable expansion.  Or just use `sed` in that case.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: @birgersp: Then, instead of `command | …`, use `myvar="$( command )"; echo ${path#$myvar/}`. It works as expected. (Note the trailing `/`) @Birger: If the path that’s to be removed uses characters that are regex/sed syntax, sed will fail. And escaping is a nightmare, that is always one bit harder than you thought it was. ^^

Answer (score 134):

If you wanted to remove a certain **NUMBER** of path components, you should use `cut` with `-d'/'`.  For example, if `path=/home/dude/some/deepish/dir`:

To remove the first two components:

```sh
# (Add 2 to the number of components to remove to get the value to pass to -f)
echo $path | cut -d'/' -f4-
# output:
# some/deepish/dir
```

To keep the first two components:

```sh
echo $path | cut -d'/' -f-3
# output:
# /home/dude
```

To remove the last two components (`rev` reverses the string):

```sh
echo $path | rev | cut -d'/' -f4- | rev
# output:
# /home/dude/some
```

To keep the last three components:

```sh
echo $path | rev | cut -d'/' -f-3 | rev
# output:
# some/deepish/dir
```

Or, if you want to remove everything before a particular component, `sed` would work:

```sh
echo $path | sed 's/.*\(some\)/\1/g'
# output:
# some/deepish/dir
```

Or after a particular component:

```sh
echo $path | sed 's/\(dude\).*/\1/g'
# output:
# /home/dude
```

It's even easier if you don't want to keep the component you're specifying:

```sh
echo $path | sed 's/some.*//g'
# output:
# /home/dude/
```

And if you want to be consistent you can match the trailing slash too:

```sh
echo $path | sed 's/\/some.*//g'
# output:
# /home/dude
```

Of course, if you're matching several slashes, you should switch the `sed` delimiter:

```sh
echo $path | sed 's!/some.*!!g'
# output:
# /home/dude
```

Note that these examples all use absolute paths, you'll have to play around to make them work with relative paths.

Comment: Amazing answer, in particular the double `rev` trick. Will upvote when my vote cap wears off tomorrow.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 :) glad it was helpful

Comment: excellent,  informative answer in the original Unix spirit, and so much better than {chopsquiggleSquiggle}:only:shellversionyoumaynothave.

Comment: Thank you for the examples! But isn't the "cut -d'/' -f-3" actually "keep the first two components (assuming leading slash)" instead of "remove the last three components"? I know it will make no difference for the exact example but it would be more generell.

Comment: To remove the last three components (no matter how many components the path has): echo $path | rev | cut -d'/' -f4- | rev

Comment: @jojoob You are correct.  Feel free to update the answer.

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow my edit was rejected with "intended to address the author [...] makes no sense as an edit". It's your content, therefore only you can change it.

Comment: @jojoob That rejection makes no sense to me either.  Sometimes SO mods and power users are crazy.  I'll see if I can fix it.  It could be your edit summary they took issue with.

Comment: This is amazing. What about to remove everything before a particular component but not keeping that component (I don't know what the next one will be) I.e. to keep everything after a specified component?

Comment: @Gamora Glad it's helpful :) To do that it's simple, just don't capture the path component you know.  So: `echo $path | sed 's/.*some//g'`
And honestly, looking at this again years later - today I would ensure that "some" wouldn't match some other dir substring - so something like `sed 's!.*/some/!!g'` (which may not work if "some" may be the basename of path).

Comment: The `sed` examples will all break horrible and silently, whenever there’s a character in the path that’s also regex/sed syntax.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine This is true any time you try to match strings that contain characters that sed assigns special meaning to.  In the examples above, if `$path` contains the sed syntax characters it's fine, while if your match string ("some" or "dude" above) contains the characters then you have to be careful.  If you're using a variable for your sed match then you have to be _really_ careful.

Answer (score 33):

If you don't want to hardcode the part you're removing:

```
$ s='/path/to/file/drive/file/path/'
$ echo ${s#$(dirname "$(dirname "$s")")/}
file/path/
```

Comment: I spent 2 hours looking how to do this. and you were the only one to post a way to display only the name of a directory without hardcoding. I needed to do: 'find /path/to/file/drive/file/*_TST -maxdepth 0 -type d' But I wanted to show only the names of directories w/o the full path. and this did it.

Comment: @Whitecat is that's what you wanted, read "man find", in particular "-printf". You can specify '-printf "%h\n"'. Just remember that it will print the directory for every matching file so you'd want to filter this through "uniq".

Answer (score 12):

One way to do this with sed is

```
echo /path/to/file/drive/file/path/ | sed 's:^/path/to/file/drive/::'
```

Comment: Awesome--I had no idea that the sed delimiter could be a ":" (colon) rather than "/" (slash).  Elegant and works perfectly.

Comment: You can use almost any delimiter with sed, not just / and : as long as you're consistent.

Comment: @Prisoner13 something new everyday!

Comment: This too will break horribly and possibly silently, whenever the path also contains regex/sed syntax. Assuming the path isn’t hard-coded, which it should not be anyway, it’s a case of Bobby Tables. ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove *the first N parts of the path*, you could of course use *N* calls to `dirname`, as in [glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988373/1221661), but it's probably easier to use globbing:

```
path=/path/to/file/drive/file/path/
echo "${path#*/*/*/*/*/}"   #  file/path/
```

Specifically, `${path#*/*/*/*/*/}` means *"return `$path` minus the shortest prefix that contains 5 slashes"*.

Answer (score 3):

Using `${path#/path/to/file/drive/}` as suggested by evil otto is certainly the typical/best way to do this, but since there are many sed suggestions it is worth pointing out that sed is overkill if you are working with a fixed string.  You can also do:

```
echo $PATH | cut -b 21-
```

To discard the first 20 characters.  Similarly, you can use `${PATH:20}` in bash or `$PATH[20,-1]` in zsh.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using evil otto's answer. The part I want to remove is fixed, but can change if I move my script to a different box/different path. So, having the part I want to remove from the path in a variable makes it easier than counting....but information you provided is good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash, without hard coding the answer

```
basenames()
{
  local d="${2}"
  for ((x=0; x<"${1}"; x++)); do
    d="${d%/*}"
  done
  echo "${2#"${d}"/}"
}
```

- **Argument 1** - How many levels do you want to keep (2 in the original question)
- **Argument 2** - The full path

Taken from [vsi_common](https://github.com/VisionSystemsInc/vsi_common/blob/0be3a23df275f780b6e0a5984a7eccb69dca3f98/linux/dir_tools.bsh#L227-L236)([original version](https://github.com/VisionSystemsInc/vsi_common/blob/ccb48bae2ef5e92cc09f241e70f853db7de07be0/linux/dir_tools.bsh#L153-L160))

Comment: OMG, best answer on this page!  I needed the general case, in the most portable constructs possible.  You nailed it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using simple bash syntax that accommodates variables (in case you don't want to hard code full paths), removes the need for piping stdin to `sed`, and includes a `for` loop, for good measure:

```
FULLPATH="/path/to/file/drive/file/path/"
SUBPATH="/path/to/file/drive/"
for i in $FULLPATH;
do
echo ${i#$SUBPATH}
done
```

as mentioned above by @evil otto, the `#` symbol is used to remove a prefix in this scenario.