# How to automatically rename tmux windows to the current directory

Tags: tmux

I would like to have tmux to automatically rename the window with the current working directory (cwd). As it is by default, it names the tab/window as the name of the current process, such as zsh or vim.

When I open a new window in tmux, the name is `reattach-to-use-namespace` and then it immediately switches to `zsh`.

[image: tmux tabs]

I'm on OS X 10.10.2, I use zshell, and I have tmux 1.9a.

To be clear, I don't want the entire path in the name of the window, just the current directory, so for example, I want `projectName`, not `/Users/username/Development/projectName`.

If you want to see my current `tmux.conf`, [here it is](https://github.com/aharris88/dotfiles/blob/b7128b10b038229c564f48a4280096a856aa650b/tmux.conf).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Expanding on what Josef wrote, you can put the basename of the directory in the status using a shell snippet:

```
# be sure to see note* below
set -g window-status-format '#I:#(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/})#F'
set -g window-status-current-format '#I:#(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/})#F'

# status bar updates every 15s by default**, change to 1s here 
# (this step is optional - a lower latency might have negative battery/cpu usage impacts)
set -g status-interval 1
```

*Note that what would be `${pwd##*/}` is escaped to `${pwd####*/}` since `#` has special meaning in the format string.

**See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175440/118308) for an example default tmux config.

Comment: This, actually, does not set window name, but only status. Use `tmux list-windows` to check.

Comment: This works brilliantly to set the window status (which is what shows up in the bottom of the screen for each window) as @paulodiovani pointed out. It's worth mentioning the `status-interval` is so that it updates faster when changing directories, but you could leave it out and the lag isn't too bad.

Comment: What's the meaning of `#I`, `#F`? Is there any doc for the syntax?

Comment: @nn0p: from the tmux map page: `#I Current window index` and `#F Current window flag` (`*` if selected)

Comment: This didn't work for me at first ("Invalid environment variable") because I used double quotes. Changing to single quotes fixed it.

Answer (score 87):

With **tmux 2.3+**, the `b:` format modifier shows the "basename" (or "tail") of a path.

```
set-option -g status-interval 5
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format '#{b:pane_current_path}'
```

The FORMATS section of `man tmux` describes other modifiers, such as `#{d:}` and even `#{s/foo/bar/:}`.

---

With **tmux 2.2 or older**, the `basename` shell command can be used instead.

```
set-option -g status-interval 5
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format '#(basename "#{pane_current_path}")'
```

Comment: Thanks for showing both ways, and since the 2.3 version will also work on newer (slightly slower since it has to shell out) I'll put that in my configs until I can get all the machines I work on to 2.3 or newer.

Comment: is there a way to get `~` for `~` rather than the full username?

Comment: @Toothrot sure! `#{b;s/your_username/~/:pane_current_path}` is the way to go

Answer (score 24):

**Show the top N components**

[image]

Showing just the basename generates too much ambiguity, but full paths are too much clutter, so I settled for:

```
the/last/path
```

instead of:

```
/a/very/long/the/last/path
```

or just:

```
path
```

`.tmux.conf`

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format '#[fg=white,bold]** #{window_index} #[fg=green]#{pane_current_command} #[fg=blue]#(echo "#{pane_current_path}" | rev | cut -d'/' -f-3 | rev) #[fg=white]**|'
set-window-option -g window-status-format '#[fg=white,bold]#{window_index} #[fg=green]#{pane_current_command} #[fg=blue]#(echo "#{pane_current_path}" | rev | cut -d'/' -f-3 | rev) #[fg=white]|'
```

Trick taken from: [Remove part of path on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986794/unix-remove-part-of-path/31728689#31728689)

If that still does not solve ambiguity, I go for:

```
bind-key -r w choose-window -F '#{window_index} | #{pane_current_command} | #{host} | #{pane_current_path}'
```

Tested on Tmux 2.1, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Partial path doesn't work for me.  When the command #(echo "#{pane_current_path}" | rev gets executed it gives output as }htap_tnerruc_enap{#  . So basically it gives input to echo after reversing.

Comment: @HrishikeshGoyal thanks for report. What is your tmux version?

Comment: I am using  tmux 2.0

Comment: One up for @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 If that still does not solve ambiguity, I go for: bind-key -r w choose-window -F '#{window_index} | #{pane_current_command} | #{host} | #{pane_current_path}'

Answer (score 15):

To get the best of both worlds - window name is path when you're at a shell prompt, but name of executable when you're running something, try this:

```
set-option -g status-interval 1
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format "#{?#{==:#{pane_current_command},bash},#{b:pane_current_path},#{pane_current_command}}"
```

Replace "bash" with whatever shell you're using.

Comment: This is sick! Thanks a million.

Comment: Awesome! If you use another shell such as `zsh`, change `bash` to `zsh`.

Comment: @Josh says that in the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Adding this config to your ~/.tmux.conf file should work:

```
set-option -g window-status-current-format '#I:#{pane_current_path}#F'
set-option -g window-status-format '#I:#{pane_current_path}#F'
set-option -g status-interval 1
```

It depends however on your Tmux version. I wasn't able to make it work on 1.9a3 (in Cygwin) - but with Tmux 1.8 on Ubuntu (in Vagrant) it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, it does nothing for me.

Comment: this works great for me (OSX/tmux 1.9a), but is there a simple way to have it just be the basename?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of it (commands from format string are in another environment) - you can try solution provided by JuniorCompressor (even if it's kind of hacky imho :]).

Answer (score 3):

I use the following in ~/.tmux.conf to achieve this (working on OSX, zsh, tmux-2.3):

```
set -g automatic-rename-format '#{pane_current_path}'
set -g status-interval 5
```

You can set status-interval to 1 to make it respond faster to changing directories.

According to the changelog (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES) this should work in tmux 1.9 and up.

Using ssh into a CentOS machine with tmux 2.3 the window name doesn't change until I press return in the new panel, not sure why that is happening.

Comment: That looks like it would be the full path, but I just wanted the current directory.

Comment: @aharris88 use `b:` to get the path tail. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010147/152142

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in a tmux session for zsh shell:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PS1=$'\ek$(basename $(pwd))\e\\> '
```

If someone uses bash shell:

```
export PS1="\033k\$(basename \$(pwd))\033\\> "
```

You can add these commands in the shell initialization file on the condition the `$TERM` env variable is set to the value `"screen"`

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. It looks like the command you gave here sets the prompt in the shell. I don't care about that. I want the windows in tmux named the current directory. I added an image to the question.

Comment: It doesn't only sets the prompt but also updates the title of the working window by running pwd command. I've tested in a debian and osx. Each time tmux shows the current working directory.

Comment: I doesn't change the tmux window name for me. And it changes the prompt to `\W $\033k/Users/adamharris\033\ `. I'm on osx and my shell is zsh instead of bash.

Comment: In case of zsh try in a tmux shell: a) setopt PROMPT_SUBST b) export PS1=$'\ek$(pwd)\e\\> '

Comment: That works. The only problem is that I'm using powerline for my prompt, and it turns my zsh into a normal prompt.

Comment: @aharris88 did you manage to find any clean solution to this that works well with powerline?

Comment: @Anchor I didn't. Also, I stopped using powerline because it's really hard to install on a new machine.

Answer (score 1):

I am using zsh hook for that

Add following in `~/.zshrc`

```
precmd () {
  if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
    tmux set-window-option -q window-status-format "#[fg=cyan bg=cyan] | #[fg=white, bg=cyan] #I | ${PWD##/*/} #[fg=cyan, bg=cyan] | "
    tmux set-window-option -q window-status-current-format "#[fg=cyan, bg=cyan] | #[fg=white, bg=cyan] #I | ${PWD##/*/} #[fg=cyan, bg=cyan] | "
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't strictly answer your question--it doesn't automatically rename an existing tmux session to the current working directory.

Rather, when creating a new session, it names that session after the current working directory.

Here's what I did:

*to*

**~/.aliases**

*add*

```
alias tm='tmux new -s `basename $PWD`'
```

Open a new terminal window and type:

`tm`

This now creates a new tmux session which is named after the current working directory.

Note: This relies on `basename` which does not exist in Windows.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit different because I was asking about renaming the window status, not the session. But that's fine, I already got an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you want use this:

```
set -g status-left '#{pane_current_path} '
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look quite right. I want it to only show the current directory, not the entire path. The accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To change what you see in the window list you can specify a format when you define the key-binding for the `chose-window` function like this:

```
bind-key '"'  choose-window  -F "#{session_name} | #{window_name} - #{b:pane_current_path} (#{pane_current_command})"
```