# How to remove end folder name from a path in Linux script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to make a simple command in Linux similar to `cd..` in `DOS`. What I tried is to make a script that changes directory to a path, which I have to get from `pwd`, by removing the last folder name.

So for a path: `/home/usr/Downloads/images` I want to get `/home/usr/Downloads`.

Comment: just put a space in between `cd` and `..`.  In DOS, that is admitted, but not in unix.  So `cd ..` would be enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove part of path on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986794/remove-part-of-path-on-unix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dirname` command to do what you're asking for, it remove the last "part" from a file. If what you give it is a directory, you'll get the parent directory.

```
parent=$(dirname /your/path/here)
```

But doing a `cd..` with a script is not possible - the `cd` would only affect the shell that the script is running in, not the shell that invoked the script.

So you have to use an alias or a function.

```
alias cd..='cd ..'
```

Or

```
cdp() {
  cd ..
}
```

Comment: i added an alias in .bashrc, though i didnt know about 'cd ..' in linux , i always used to try 'cd..'