# No such file or directory when populating variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

When I run the following command in a bash script:

```
urlOfServer="$($repoURL_StripLastFour | awk -F'/' '{print $1}')"
```

I get the following error:

```
192.168.1.12:7999/pcfpt/scriptsforexamples: No such file or directory
```

You can see that the value of the `repoURL_StripLastFour` variable is `192.168.1.12:7999/pcfpt/scriptsforexamples` at the time when the script is run.  This value is auto-created at runtime by other elements of the script, so I cannot simply pass it as a literal.

**What specific syntax is required to resolve this error, so that the `urlOfServer` variable can be successfully populated?**

I have tried many variations of moving quotes and parentheses already.

Comment: With bash's Parameter Expansion: `urlOfServer="${repoURL_StripLastFour%%/*}"`

Comment: [How to remove last part of a path in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28771/56041), [How to delete part of a path in an interactive shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21788/56041), [Remove part of path on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10986794/608639), [How to remove end folder name from a path in Linux script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29329093/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww You left evidence that you drove through here and downvoted both excellent answers and the OP in one rushed slashing event.  I do not care if you downvote my question, but please consider not treating the answerers so harshly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
$repoURL_StripLastFour
```

with

```
echo "$repoURL_StripLastFour"
```

to feed awk from [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) or replace

```
$repoURL_StripLastFour | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'
```

with

```
awk -F'/' '{print $1}' <<< "$repoURL_StripLastFour"
```

to use a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).

Comment: Thanks mentioning `<<<` is a bashism

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `awk`; just use parameter expansion:

```
urlOfServer=${repoURL_StripLastFour%%/*}
```

`%%/*` strips the longest suffix that matches `/*`, namely the first `/` and everything after it, leaving only the text preceding the first `/`.