# Remove part of a string by using bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, path

I have the path `/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/NG-VOSGQL239-JOB1` and would like to get just `/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/` How can I delete the last part of the path if it can be with different lengths by using Bash?

Comment: You could try parameter expansion here like `val="/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/NG-VOSGQL239-JOB1" ; echo ${val%/*}`.

Comment: Why is python listed in the tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove part of path on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10986794/608639), [How to remove end folder name from a path in Linux script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29329093/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bash regex `=~`:

```
$ var=/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/NG-VOSGQL239-JOB
$ [[ $var =~ .*/ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/
```

Comment: `if [[ $var =~ (.*)/ ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; else echo .; fi` would be a more complete emulation of basename behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Some common ways to do that are:

```
$ str=/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/NG-VOSGQL239-JOB1
$ echo "${str%/*}"                                # fast, but wrong if str has no "/"s in it
/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir
$ dirname "$str"                                  # slow, but returns "." for bare names
/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir
$ echo "$str" | sed 's@/[^/]*$@@'                 # more general, but slow *and* wrong with no "/"s
/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir
```

Note, in the above, we use "wrong" to indicate unexpected behavior in the case of path manipulation.  (eg, we define the output of `dirname`  to be the correct behavior.)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `sed`; you are just reimplementing `dirname` with no upside. (`dirname` is just as much part of POSIX as `sed` is.)

Comment: Agree that  `sed` is the wrong tool for this case.  But `echo | sed ...` is a common idiom for string manipulation, and can be generalized.

Answer (score 2):

Use [dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname)

```
dirname /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/NG-VOSGQL239-JOB
```

Comment: The one reason to prefer `dirname` over the parameter expansion `"${s%/*}"` is that dirname returns `.` if there are no `/`s in a filename at all. That's sometimes a compelling difference, but you take a big performance hit to `fork()` a subprocess and then load and execute an external command on behalf of that difference.