# How to remove everything from path after a word using sed in bash/ shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Where the word is repeated and only wanted to be removed from specific word location

```
Lets say my path is - /opt/xyz/config/config.xml
```

```
Solution I want after using sed is: /opt/xyz/config/
```

how can this be obtained?

I am sick of using  {sed 's/config.*//'} >> This actually removes both config words
such as it looks

```
/opt/xyz/
```

I have tried using this in multiple ways

```
>  sed 's/config.*//'
```

Comment: `echo /opt/xyz/config/config.xml | sed 's/config\.xml//'`

Comment: Only when the filename matches the previous directory?  Or are you looking to always remove the filename part of the path?  It's not clear what your rule is.  Your `sed` fails because you are replacing the match of 'config' and anything after with nothing.

Comment: See: [How to remove end folder name from a path in Linux script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29329093/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with something like this?

```bash
sed 's/[^/]*$//'
```

But if the filepath is in a shell variable then you might as well use:

```bash
mydir=${myfilepath%/*}/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution, depending on your use-case, is the [`dirname`](https://ss64.com/bash/dirname.html) bash function, e.g.

```
dirname /opt/xyz/config/config.xml
/opt/xyz/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH parameter expansion:

```
p="/opt/xyz/config/config.xml"; echo "${p%/*}"
/opt/xyz/config
```