# Need to remove the last 3 words from a file path using Shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am new to Shell scripting. I wanted to remove last 3 words from a file path including the file extension. Below is the example,

Input:

```
/tmp/errorlog_invest_CR12345_88_1:05:45.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
/tmp/errorlog_invest
```

Kindly help me to get the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: define "last 3 words"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need to look at this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986794/unix-remove-part-of-path)

**You will find following solutions on this URL 
I am not able add comment so I am Just copy paste Ans**

If you wanted to remove a certain NUMBER of path components, you should use cut with -d'/'. For example, if path=/home/dude/some/deepish/dir:

To remove the first two components:

$ echo $path | cut -d'/' -f4-
some/deepish/dir

To remove the last three components (assuming no trailing slash):

$ echo $path | cut -d'/' -f-3
/home/dude

To KEEP the last three components (rev reverses the string):

$ echo $path | rev | cut -d'/' -f-3 | rev
some/deepish/dir

Or, if you want to remove everything before a particular component, sed would work:

$ echo $path | sed 's/.*(some)/\1/g'
some/deepish/dir

Or after a particular component:

$ echo $path | sed 's/(dude).*/\1/g'
/home/dude

It's even easier if you don't want to keep the component you're specifying:

$ echo $path | sed 's/some.*//g'
/home/dude/

And if you want to be consistent you can match the trailing slash too:

$ echo $path | sed 's//some.*//g'
/home/dude

Of course, if you're matching several slashes, you should switch the sed delimiter:

$ echo $path | sed 's!/some.*!!g'
/home/dude

Also, if you have filenames with / characters in them, you're totally boned.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the answer. It was really helpful.